# Unable to resize correctly nested Pane JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2

I've the current situation: a main windows with a main `BorderPane`. At the center of it I have an `AnchorPane` with some objects inside. I want to distribute the objects equally inside the height of the pane, even if the pane is resized.

The problem I'm falled in is that all things works when the resize increase the height of the pane. When I decrease the size of the window, the pane's height continue to increase.

I have reproduced the error in this example application using a simple line (in my application I've also a line like this):

```
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ResizeProblem extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        AnchorPane inner = new AnchorPane();

        Line line = new Line();

        // comment from here...
        root.setCenter(inner);
        Pane pane = inner;
        // ...to here and uncomment next to make things work
        //Pane pane = root;

        line.startXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
        line.endXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
        line.setStartY(0.);
        line.endYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());

        pane.heightProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> System.out.println("ov: " + ov + " nv: " + nv));

        pane.getChildren().add(line);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Resize Problem");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I've seen that avoiding nesting, everything works as expected.

What's wrong with that?

Please help me find the right direction.

Comment: Just for your info:
Use number + d instead of number + dot  (line.setStartY(0d);) 
II think that's a better style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my explanation ..

`BorderPane` does not resize its children to its layout `Bounds`, it careless, same goes to `AnchorPane` and even `Pane`, when you have one nesting, your line ending point is matched with the `Pane`'s height, so automatically it obeys what ever value is being restricted on it, but if you nest an `AnchorPane` in a `BorderPane` who is going to take care of the kids? `BorderPane` and `AnchorPane` is a bad marriage, unless you want to put them in a contract marriage where you manually check each individual's height and alignment, so the `BorderPane`'s height increases and the `AnchorPane` does the same, and your respect matching is to the parent. Also your `static` reference of `inner` is a `Pane`, and with `Pane` you have to manually position your children in your `Node`, `Pane` does not do that for you so using `Pane` means your children will be street kids wondering around.

Hope it helpful